# DirectAccess not connecting on clients with temporary ipv6 addresses

Tags: direct-access

Our **DirectAccess** solution is working fine.
We have hundreds of clients connected every day.

But *sometimes*, clients with *Temporary IPv6 Addresses* are not connecting.
Even after performing:

- Restart connection
- Restart interface
- Restart OS

None of the above helps until we **disable** *IPv6 temporary addresses*. Then they connect correctly after restart.

Is anyone else having this issue?

What can we do to support clients connecting through temporary IPv6 addresses?